# Connecting an optris to an arduino uno to send and receive hex strings

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ir

I have an optris CT IR sensor, data sheet below.

Is it possible to connect the Uno to the sensor, so I can send a hex string (01) and hopefully receive a hex string from the sensor (04 D3)?

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwirjO3oxo7PAhVKDsAKHcjGAcMQFggvMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.optris.com%2Foptris-ct-lt%3Ffile%3Dtl_files%2Fpdf%2FDownloads%2FCompact%2520Series%2FData%2520Sheet%2520optris%2520CT%2520LT.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEb-UKhxvfBE7k7k8zOgEZE9TOJbg&cad=rja

Commands below: (Go to examples section for 01, 04 D3)
https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM6_zAx47PAhXoIcAKHVdUCo8QFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.optris.co.uk%2Finterfaces%3Ffile%3Dtl_files%2Fdownloads%2FManuals%2Faddendums-de-en%2Fct-ctlaser-commands.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEkEtwUoiM6jsJYOnGD4-8Yo2Cprg&bvm=bv.132653024,d.ZGg

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are interface options that are compatible with the Arduino. You just have to ensure that you choose the right model so you have the right interface available. Options include RS-232 (with a MAX232 adapter), RS-485 (with a suitable RS-485 shield), CAN (with a suitable CAN shield), Ethernet (with a suitable Ehernet shield) and maybe even the USB version (with the USB Host shield), though the latter is less likely to work.

Pick one that suits your needs best.